# Mathematica can't simplify some logarithmic expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

When I simplify some logarithmic expressions in Mathematica, it just returns the expression

```
FullSimplify[Log[Sqrt[2] + 1, 5 Sqrt[2] + 7]]

FullSimplify[Log[Sqrt[2] + 1, 17 - 12 Sqrt[2]]]
```

[image]

Obviously, simplification isn't completely, using *Maple* could get
[image]
[image]

Is there any way I can tell Mathematica to be smarter?

**Additional**

`RootApproximant` only worked on numeric quantity

```
FullSimplify[Log[(5 Sqrt[2] + 7)^c, (2 Sqrt[2] + 3)^a (17 - 12 Sqrt[2])^b], {a,b,c}∈Reals]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to solve the same problem in equation form:

```
Reduce[(Sqrt[2] + 1)^n == 5 Sqrt[2] + 7, n, Integers]
```

> n == 3

```
Reduce[(Sqrt[2] + 1)^n == 17 - 12 Sqrt[2], n, Integers]
```

> n == -4

```
Reduce[
  (5 Sqrt[2] + 7)^(c*n) == (3 + 2 Sqrt[2])^a (17 - 12 Sqrt[2])^b
  \[And] a != 0 \[And] b != 0 \[And] c != 0,
  n, Reals
]
```

> a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && n == -((-2 a + 4 b)/(3 c))

Answer (score 8):

Use [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html)

```
y1 = Log[Sqrt[2] + 1, 5 Sqrt[2] + 7];

y1 // RootApproximant

(* 3 *)
```

Verifying,

```
y1 == 3 // FullSimplify

(* True *)

y2 = Log[2 Sqrt[2] + 3, 17 - 12 Sqrt[2]];

y2 // RootApproximant

(* -2 *)
```

Verifying,

```
y2 == -2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```